# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire and AlamofireImage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I am installing Alamofire, AlamofireImage and some other pods. pod target is a magplusframework, and my app target using the magplusframework which all pods have been installed.

Everything is fine but when I run the app. App got crashed and show error.

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
>     Referenced from: /Users/abc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-bbrgqfddrolbzefvpttmxgmmkkqn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/magplusframework.framework/magplusframework
>
> Reason: image not found

I also tried Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries to YES in both the target magplusframework and my app target. but it did't worked.

Comment: You need to add "magplusframework" in Embedded binaries.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. already added

Comment: CMD + Option + Shift + K (Deep Clean) and delete files in the XCode DrivedData  folder. And then build again.

Comment: Did this multiple time and code compiled successfully but when run the ipa app crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the issue after adding the framework in embeded SDK

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. You can check the apple root certificate in the keychain and change the trust to the system default